# clang redefinition of symbols in different namespaces error

Tags: c++, g++, clang, linker-errors

I am trying to compile following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
inline void blah() {
    std::cout << "123" << std::endl;
};
}

namespace NN {
extern "C" {
inline void blah() {
    std::cout << "123" << std::endl;
};
}
}

int main() {
    blah();
    return 0;
};
```

g++ compiles without errors, but clang:

```
x.cpp:11:13: error: redefinition of 'blah'
inline void blah() {
            ^
x.cpp:4:13: note: previous definition is here
inline void blah() {
            ^
1 error generated.
```

Is it possible to fix compilation for clang?

Comment: the obvious solution is "don't do this", in particular don't put an `extern "C"` function inside a namespace

Comment: I'm also concerned about making extern C function inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `extern "C"` part, because that makes the function callable from C (and everything else that can call C functions) which have no namespaces, meaning both functions are the same C-callable symbol.

It has nothing to do with Clang, it's a C++ thing so should not work with any compiler.

---

In the C++11 standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) from 2012), the relevant passages are in §7.5/6, the most important being the beginning:

> At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two declarations for a function with C language linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function.

About error messages, the specification also says

> ... no diagnostic is required if the declarations appear in different translation units

GCC Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25940